# Filter values relative to values in another column using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column in a dataframe and I would like to filter out any rows that are over or under two standard deviations from the mean.

As an example, I would hope to get two rows out of this (only the rows that fall between the low and high standard deviations:

```
group    value    low_sd    high_sd    
a          4        2          8
a          1        2          8
b          6        4          9
b          12       4          9
```

I was hoping to use `dplyr::between` .

```
clean_df <- df%>%
  filter(between(value, low_sd, high_sd))
```

But it seems `between` only takes numerical values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use `between()` from `data.table`:

```
df %>%
 filter(data.table::between(value, low_sd, high_sd))

  group value low_sd high_sd
1     a     4      2       8
2     b     6      4       9
```

Or if you want to stick just to `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 filter(dplyr::between(value, low_sd, high_sd))
```

Answer (score 4):

The `between` is not vectorized for `left`, `right` values. Instead, this can be done by using only the comparison (`>/<`) operators

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    filter(value > low_sd, value <= high_sd)
#    group value low_sd high_sd
#1     a     4      2       8
#2     b     6      4       9
```

---

But if we wrap with `Vectorize`, it would work as well

```
df %>% 
   filter(Vectorize(dplyr::between)(value, low_sd, high_sd))
#    group value low_sd high_sd
#1     a     4      2       8
#2     b     6      4       9
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(group = c("a", "a", "b", "b"), value = c(4L, 1L, 
6L, 12L), low_sd = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 4L), high_sd = c(8L, 8L, 9L, 
9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```